# The second-order Eulerian numbers meet the Clausen numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, eulerian-numbers

The (generalized) Clausen numbers [A160014](https://oeis.org/A160014) are defined as

$$\operatorname{C}_{n, k} = \prod_{ p\, -\, k\, |\, n} p \quad (p \in \mathbb{P})$$ where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the primes.
The classical Clausen numbers are $\operatorname{C}_{n} = \prod_{ p-1\, |\,n} p$. They are by the von Staudt-Clausen theorem the denominators of the Bernoulli numbers. Define

$$ b_{n} \, = \, \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k \frac{\left\langle\!\!\left\langle n-1\atop k+1\right\rangle\!\!\right\rangle} {\binom {2n-1}{k+1}}$$

where $ \left\langle\!\!\left\langle n\atop k\right\rangle\!\!\right\rangle$ are the second-order Eulerian numbers [A340556](https://oeis.org/A340556).
Apparently the product $\operatorname{C}_{n}b_{n}$ are integers.
$$\operatorname{C}_{n}b_{n} \in \mathbb{N} \quad (n \ge 0) $$

If this is true, it needs proof. Who can give it?

Comment: Why define $C_{n,k}$ if you only use $C_n$? Typos anywhere?

Comment: It can never hurt to state things from a general context. And besides, this way I can refer to a place that I know for sure contains further relevant information.